# Business Central AL Code Hyperlink Method

Tags: dynamics-business-central, dynamics-al

I need to display a URL during the login process in Business Central.  Have an event on the OnAfterLoginStart event.  Part of the event code will display a Terms of Service.  Displaying the terms of service page as following:  Hyperlink(TOS_URL);

Executing this no new tab is created.

If I do:
Message('New TOS must be approved');
Hyperlink(TOS_URL);

then the message is displayed and a new tab is created - as expected.

Same code (Hyperlink(TOS_URL);) works as expected if I put it on a button click on a window.

Is there something in the Business Central base code where a re-direct is not allowed before the login process completes?

Is there another way to accomplish this task without the message statement?

Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the event `OnShowTermsAndConditions` in `LogInManagement` the hyperlink works , however my browser blocked the opening of a new window/tab.

An alternative solution could be to create a Control Addin that display your terms of service and then open a page in Business Central with the Control Addin on it.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I'll have to learn more about the Control Addin it might be useful in other features we are working on.